# How to filter rows based on datetime index

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

```
I have a dataframe that has an index of date type and contains hourly data per day.

I need to take only the rows which have the last record of the day 
and filter out REST OF THE RECORDS FOR THAT DAY ONLY... 

and do the same for other days.
```

```py
                   COL-A
DATE    
2014-01-01 00:56:00     NaN
2014-01-01 01:56:00     NaN
2014-01-01 02:56:00     NaN
2014-01-01 03:56:00     NaN
2014-01-01 04:00:00     NaN
2014-01-01 04:56:00     42.0
2014-01-01 05:56:00     NaN
2014-01-01 06:56:00     NaN
2014-01-01 07:56:00     NaN
2014-01-01 08:56:00     NaN
2014-01-01 09:56:00     NaN
2014-01-01 10:00:00     19.0
2014-01-01 10:56:00     NaN
2014-01-01 11:56:00     NaN
2014-01-01 12:56:00     NaN
2014-01-01 13:56:00     NaN
2014-01-01 14:56:00     NaN
2014-01-01 15:56:00     NaN
2014-01-01 16:00:00     NaN
2014-01-01 16:56:00     36.0
2014-01-01 17:56:00     NaN
2014-01-01 18:56:00     NaN
2014-01-01 19:56:00     NaN
2014-01-01 20:56:00     NaN
2014-01-01 21:56:00     NaN
2014-01-01 22:00:00     NaN
2014-01-01 22:56:00     NaN
2014-01-01 23:56:00     NaN
2014-01-01 23:59:00     41.0
2014-01-02 00:56:00     NaN
...
...
...
```

I need to keep only the row 
`2014-01-01 23:59:00     41.0`

Comment: or just `df.resample('D').last()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
df.groupby([pd.Grouper(key = 'DATE', freq = 'd')]).last()
```

Comment: it threw up 'Grouper named DATE is not found' so i removed ```key='DATE'``` and kept only
 ```df.groupby([pd.Grouper(freq = 'd')]).last()```
... looks like it works.. 
will it give unexpected result?

Comment: Since the DATE is already index. it should not give any unexpected results.